# how to filter xml elements for multiple values

Tags: sql-server, xml

XML is stored in a table in SQL server using xml data type.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable(
 i int primary key,   
XmlField xml NULL
)
insert into  MyTable(i, xmlField)  
values(1, N'<root>  
<Area1>  
 <Parent> 
     <Name>ParentJay</Name>
 <Spouse>Janice</Spouse>
     <child>John
        <grandchild>Kate</grandchild>
        <grandchild>Moss</grandchild>
        <grandchild>Ruby</grandchild>
        <grandchild>Violet</grandchild>
</child>
</Parent>
<Parent> 
<Name>ParentMark</Name>
<Spouse>May</Spouse>
<child>Mary
        <grandchild>Violet</grandchild>
        <grandchild>Kate</grandchild>
        <grandchild>jubi</grandchild>
</child>
</Parent>
<Parent> 
<Name>ParentJoe</Name>
<Spouse>kim</Spouse>
<child>Kelly
        <grandchild>Moss</grandchild>
        <grandchild>Kate</grandchild>
</child>
</Parent>
<Parent> 
<Name>ParentMike</Name>
<Spouse>Mia</Spouse>
<child>Mary
        <grandchild>Jeff</grandchild>
        <grandchild>jubi</grandchild>
        <grandchild>Violet</grandchild>
</child>
</Parent>
</Area1>
</root>')
```

Problem: Get all the child nodes with grandchild names Kate and Moss

I have query to get the child element to filter by one grandchild Kate.

Is there a way to use and/or in the query to filter for multiple grandchild names(Kate and Moss).

```
declare @v varchar(20) 
set @v='Kate'
SELECT  
child = x.value('local-name(..)', 'varchar(50)'),
value = x.value('(..)', 'varchar(50)') 
FROM   MyTable
CROSS APPLY XmlField.nodes('/root/Area1/Parent/child/*[contains((.),sql:variable("@v"))] ' ) as T2(x) 

Result
child   value
child   John    KateMossRubyViolet
child   Mary    VioletKatejubi
child   Kelly    MossKate


Result looking for:
child   value
child   John    KateMossRubyViolet
child   Kelly    MossKate
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, you've placed your filter predicate on a level to deep...

You might use a query like this

```
SELECT grCh.query('.')
FROM mytable
CROSS APPLY xmlField.nodes('/root/Area1/Parent[child[grandchild="Kate" and grandchild="Moss"]]') A(grCh);
```

You can read this as: Dive into root -> Area1 -> Parent. At this level we need a predicate. Here we say: Is there a node `<child>`, which (one more predicate) has a grandchild named Kate and one Moss (you can use `or` as well).

You can introduce the values with `sql:variable()` or with `sql:column()` if you don't want to hardcode them literally.

Hope this helps...